# Filtering by date in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I am looking for a way to count all entries to my ember.store today. To achieve that I wrote this controller method:

```
// controllers/todos-controller.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['time'],
  sortAscending: false,
  actions: {
    createTodo: function() {
      var title = this.get('newTitle');
      if (!title.trim()) { return; }

      var todo = this.store.createRecord('todo', {
         title: title
      });
      this.set('newTitle', '');
     todo.save();
    }
  },
  countTodos: function() {
    // count all todos added since midnight
    var d = new Date();
    d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    return this.gte('time', d).get('length');
  }.property('@each.time'),
});
```

and with the model

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  time: DS.attr('string', {
    defaultValue: function() { return new Date(); }
  })
});
```

However, when I call `countTodos`, I am getting the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Based on [the documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_filter) I thought I could apply `gte` to the Array. **How can I count by date instead?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry wanted to comment instead but i don't have enoguh reputation ...

In fact in your `countTodos` the `this` refers to your `arrayController`and arrayController do not have a method `.gte`

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html

**[UPDATE]**

as request in question :

One way of filter the content in Ember arrayControllers : (if you need to filter the content displayed by your {{each}} loop in your template without actually tuching the "content" use `arrangedContent` property, if it's just for getting an arrayCopy of with filtred element just use it inside your custom function ... :)

```
 arrangedContent : function(){
    var data = this.get("content");
    data=data.filter(function(modelInstance){
       //return true if the data should be in array false otherwise
       //examples :
       return modelInstance.get("myDateProperty")>new Date()
       //2
       return modelInstance.get("myStringProperty").match(new RegExp("myterms","myRegexp"))
       //and so on ....

    });
    return data;
 }
```

Comment: Hi MrVinz, thank you for your reply. How could I filter by a range instead of boolean comparison?

Comment: You have several ways of filtering data in an arrayController the most flexible one is to use "arrangedContent" alongside with the array filter property. [link](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_filter)

Comment: MrVinz, Thank you for your code suggestion. It worked fine. The code example is missing the closing ")" before the return statement.